# Is it possible to setup tinyproxy as a forward-proxy and reverse-proxy at the same time?

Tags: tinyproxy

I want to setup tinyproxy as forward-proxy and reverse-proxy at the same time. Is it possible? If yes, what does the config look like? And is there any limit or concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following instruction in tinyproxy documentation:

```
# When using tinyproxy as a reverse proxy, it is STRONGLY recommended
# that the normal proxy is turned off by uncommenting the next directive.
#
#ReverseOnly Yes
```

So I guess it's not recommended to use it as forward proxy and reverse proxy as the same time.